# Differential equation solution to initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, initial-value-problems, matrix-exponential

I recently went across the IVP and decided to explore it for my class. Though I still don't get how to get the solution. I have worked some of it up but I'm stuck, does anyone know how to continue?

**Given**:
$$\dot{x}=Ax$$

**With solution**:
$$x(t)=e^{At}x(0)$$

**My workings**:
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= Ax \\
\dot{x}-Ax& = 0 \\
e^{-At}\dot{x}-Ae^{-At}x& = 0\\
e^{-At}\dot{x}-\frac{d}{dt}(Ae^{-At}x)&=0
\\ Ae^{-At}x&=0
\end{align}

Then I'm stuck, did I do this correctly or did I miss anything?

Comment: Yes, you did miss that $x=x(t)$ so that you have to apply the product rule.

Comment: Line 3 is $\frac{d}{dt} (e^{-At} x) = 0$

Comment: Could you clarify? As applying the product rule in line 3 won't it just cancel the $e^{-At}\dot{x}$?

Comment: In going from line 3 to line four, you've supposed $\frac{d}{dt}(e^{-At}x)=e^{-At}x$. But the product rule demands $$\frac{d}{dt}e^{-At}x=e^{-At}\frac{dx}{dt}+x \frac{d}{dt}e^{-At}=e^{-At}\dot{x}-Ae^{-At}x.$$ So the step from line 3 to line 4 doesn't work. (The above line does give a pretty strong hint about what the correct implication is, though...)

Comment: @Semiclassical yes thats true, so I mean won't it just result in: $$e^{-At}\dot{x}-(e^{-At}\dot{x}-Ae^{-At}x)=0$$ So, it could be cancelled? Though the I'm more confused on how to get x(0).

Comment: You're looking at your fourth line, but you shouldn't: You obtained it from the (correct) third line using an invalid substitution. So you have no reason to trust it.